# Dynamically adding functionality to an object

Tags: vb.net, decorator

I am having the following problem:

I obtain an object from an external component and what I'd like to do is override several of the object's functions in order to change parts of its behavior.

I tried doing this via a decorator by inheriting from the original object's class and storing the original object as a member variable, but then I would have to override all the functions in that object.

I also don't have access to most of the object's internal data, so I cannot just clone it into my derived object's base class.

So bottom line is: is there anyway to override a couple of an already instantiated object's functions while retaining the data and not having to override the entire object functionality?

Thanks,

PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, No.

The longer answer is to write a wrapper around it and yes that means implementing all the methods. YOu can do this via composition.

.Net isn't a dynamic language although it has some dynamic feature but I don't think you component will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not inherit the object its self and then just add your methods to it?

If this isn't possible I'd store the component in a variable and then replicate all of the components methods.  Not the nicest of the solutions but it would work, I just hope the component doesn't have to many methods.

Finally have you tried **if your license agreement allows it** using something like reflector on it, might show up a possible solution.

Comment: what do you mean by inherit the object itself?

Also, the object itself has something like 40 methods, but I guess if worst does come to worst I'll do it that way.

As for your reflector suggestion can you elaborate?

Comment: Reflector ( http://www.reflector.net/ ) allows you to decompile DDL/exe ect so that you can see what makes it up.  When you say component what is it anyway?